# Array Compare in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have two arrays, one is two dimensional and another one dimensional as:

```
array1 = [["San Francisco", 8], ["New York", 3], ["Madison", 2], ["Washington", 3], ["Tulsa", 3]]

array2 = ["Durham", "Rochester", "New York", "Tulsa", "Kenner", "Washington", "Linton", "Kansas City", "San Francisco", "Madison"]
```

I want to compare the arrays for existence of City Name in both arrays and show total users as given in the first array (second elements) or 0 if the city is not in first array.

The output should be like this:

```
Durham (0)
Rochester (0)
New York (3)
Tulsa(3)
Kenner (0)
Washington (3)
...
```

How can I achive this in Rails?

EDIT:
Actually I have tried array1-array2 to get the differences and adding the differences to array1 with second value 0 but this didn't work for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: -1. Question is not clear. What gives `Tulsa (0)`?

Comment: It is obviously a mistake, what with the immediate downvoting?

Comment: What have you written to try to solve this? SO expects an attempt before you ask for code. See http://sscce.org/

Comment: I Edited the question. Sorry will keep it in mind from now on. Thanks @the Tin Man.

Comment: Downvoting is how other members say they think your question isn't valuable. Why is difficult to say, but I suspect it's for the same reason I mentioned. You didn't create a good question, you basically asked for code and didn't show you'd done any work. That doesn't go over well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array1` is a perfect candidate to be converted to Hash.

```
h=Hash[array1]
array2.each{|city| puts "%s(%d)" % [city, h[city]||0] }
```

Comment: This does not give the same output as the OPs.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Anton! it worked with a '}' at the end!

Comment: Fixed it for the future generations.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Array#assoc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-assoc):

```
array1 = [["San Francisco", 8], ["New York", 3], ["Madison", 2], ["Washington", 3], ["Tulsa", 3]]
array2 = ["Durham", "Rochester", "New York", "Tulsa", "Kenner", "Washington", "Linton", "Kansas City", "San Francisco", "Madison"]

mapping = Hash[array1]
mapping.default = 0
array2.each do |city|
  puts "#{city} (#{mapping[city]})"
end
```

Comment: In a code review I'd request the ternary statement be taken out of the string interpolation.  The use of `assoc` will slow the code as either array grows because it walks the array to find the target.

Comment: @theTinMan, Thank you for advice. I removed `assoc`, conditional expression from the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking at array uniq, and intersection (&).